# I got a message when importing tensorflow in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

When I import `tensorflow` in Python I get this error:

> C:\Users\Sathsara\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\Lib\site-packages\h5py__init__.py:36:
>   FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from
>   float to np.floating is deprecated. In future, it will be treated
>   as np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type.   from ._conv import
>   register_converters as _register_converters

Comment: The library that TensorFlow uses causes this error.
What you could do is to try to update the library or just wait untill they do it (if it's released).

Answer (score 4):

Its not an error, its just informing you that in future releases the this feature or behaviour is going to change or be no longer available.

This is important if you plan to reuse this code with different versions of python and tensorflow.

Answer (score 4):

You could upgrade h5py to a more recent version. It worked for me.

> sudo pip3 install h5py==2.8.0rc1